# Replace string part with regexp

Tags: regex

I had string

```
action = 'http://moskva.test.ru'
```

and varidable

```
domain = "kiev"
```

I need to change 'moskva' to 'kiev' with regexp (beacuse domain wiil be changed)

I try this

```
action = action.replace(/(?:http|https)\:\/\/(.*)\..*/, domain)
```

But this change all string to **kiev**, not only needed part

Comment: You can use the following regex :      /(http[s]?:\/\/)(\w+)(.*)/     and replace with $1kiev$3      Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/rP8yO1/4

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture what you want to keep, and only match what you need to replace:

```js
var action = 'http://moskva.test.ru';
var domain = "kiev";
action = action.replace(/((?:http|https)\:\/\/)[^.]*(\S*)/, "$1"+domain+"$2");
console.log(action);
```

It is not clear from the question if you have URLs as standalone strings or not, so I replaced the final `.*` with `\S*`.

*Details*:

- `((?:http|https)\:\/\/)` - Group 1 that will be referenced with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than `.`
- `(\S*)` - Group 2 that will match zero or more non-whitespace chars (your `.*` will match any 0+ chars other than a newline) as many as possible.